# Цикломатическая сложность

Tags: c++, метрики, анализ

Мне необходимо оценить сложность программы вычислив цикломатическое число Маккейба z(G): **z(G) = e - v + 2p**, где

- е — число дуг ориентированного графа Q;
- v — число вершин;
- р — число компонентов связности графа.

[Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)

Анализ нужно делать исходного кода программы написанного на C++.

Кто уже это проходил, пожалуйста, опишите словесно этот процесс, ибо в интернетах очень мало нужной информации и в основном вся информация про математическую часть этого вопроса.

Comment: а в чём кокретно проблема? вычислить число компонент связности?

Comment: Основная проблема -- это собственно разбор кода не С++. Тут был в чем-то похожий вопрос по подсчету метрик типа [SLOC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0). Попробуйте поискать его на сайте, там были (ЕМНИП) рассмотрены разные подходы.

Comment: Я уже делал метрику типа SLOC, я не могу понять, что в коде будет графом, вершиной и т.д. Как определить эти вещи?

Comment: А это вам нужен для начала парсер C++. Цам по себе парсер — сложная штука, а уж парсер C++ — втройне. Если это учебное задание, потребуйте книжку и разберитесь, как именно это делать. Если это задание по работе, потребуйте бонус, позицию по крайней мере миддла, денег на книжку, прочитайте книжку и разберитесь. Такие вещи не объясняются на пальцах.

Comment: Опреаторы -- вершины, пути передачи управления -- дуги. Например, в оператор `if` входит одна дуга (если метки оторвать в пустые операторы), а выходят две -- then и else. В функцию входит несколько дуг -- из точек, где она вызывается, а выходят дуги из ее операторов return и т.п.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В статье Википедии, на которую вы ссылаетесь, достаточно понятно описано.

Рассмотрим поток выполнения какой-нибудь простой функции. Например, такой:

```
int log(unsigned int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        throw new invalid_argument();
    int result = 0;
    while (n > 1)
    {
        n /= 2;
        result++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

У нас есть неделимые группы команд:

```
    if (n == 0)  // (1)
```

```
        throw new invalid_argument(); // (2)
```

```
    int result = 0; // (3)
```

```
    while (n > 1) // (4)
    {
```

```
        n /= 2;  // (5)
        result++;
```

```
    }
    return result; // (6)
```

Получаем такой граф:

```
(1)
 | \
 |  \
 |  (2)
(3)   \
 |     * 
(4) <----
 | \     |
 |  \   /
 |   (5)
(6)
 |
 *
```

То есть вам нужно:

1. Распарсить текст на C++. (Это очень сложно, кстати.)
2. Построить граф выполнения (Это уже легко.)
3. Подсчитать нужную числовую характеристику этого графа (тут вообще нечего делать, по сравнению с остальными пунктами).

Удачи! У вас сложное задание.

Comment: Точно, последовательности надо схлопывать. Что-то я сразу, когда коммент писал, не догодался.

Comment: @avp: Мне сейчас даже кажется, что можно и не схлопывать — это на количество циклов в графе не повлияет (а вроде бы важно только оно). Но сам граф будет больше.

Comment: @VladD Можете ещё объяснить на вашем примере, как узнать число компонентов связности графа?

Comment: @АлексейЯгело: Количество компонент связности — это грубо говоря количество разных изолированных кусков. Оно считается так: вначале список компонент связности (назовём их группами) пустой. Обходим вершины в произвольном порядке. Для каждой вершины, если она соединена с вершиной из какой-то группы, добавляем её в эту группу. Если она соединена с вершинами из нескольких групп, эти группы объединяем. Если она не соединена ни с одной из уже рассмотренных вершин, делаем для неё новую группу.

Comment: @АлексейЯгело: Но для вашего случая по идее всегда будет одна компонента связности, потому что все возможные пути выполнения начинаются в начале.

Comment: @АлексейЯгело: Хотя... Возможны идиотские случаи. Например, если какая-то часть кода никогда не выполняется. Например, такая процедура: `return 0; int i = 5; return i; return 15;` имеет три несвязанных куска, то есть 3 компоненты связности. При этом вторая и третья компоненты никогда не будут выполнены, очевидно. Так что это идиотский случай. Поддерживать ли его — решать вам.

Comment: @АлексейЯгело: Для случая из ответа: 1. Рассматриваем вершину (1). Она ни с кем из рассмотренных вершин не соединена, выделяем ей отдельную группу №1. 2. Рассматриваем вершину (4). Она с рассмотренной вершиной (1) не соединена — выделяем ей отдельную группу №2. 3. Рассматриваем вершину (2). Она соединена с (1), добавляем её в группу №1. 4. Рассматриваем вершину (6). Она соединена с вершиной (4) — добавляем её в группу №2.

Comment: 5. Рассматриваем вершину (3). Она соединена с (1) и (4), значит, сливаем вместе группы №1 и №2 и добавляем туда эту вершину. 6. Рассматриваем вершину (5). Она соединена с (4), добавляем её в единственную оставшуюся группу. Всё, вершины закончились, результат — одна группа.