# Нарисовать графы по коду

Tags: c#

Помогите нарисовать графы Мак-Кейба по данному коду.
(можно в Paint) Буду очень признателен. Я нарисовал но оказались не совсем правильными.

```
public bool CheckForPlace(int row, int pnumber)
        {
            foreach (Place p in free_places)
                if (row == p.row && pnumber == p.place_number)
                    return true;
            return false;
        }
```

и отдельно по:

```
 public Movie SearchMovie(DateTime date, string name)
        {
            // поиск сеанса с заданной датой и названием
            foreach (Movie m in movies)
                if (m.datetime.Date == date && m.name == name)
                    return m;
                else
                    continue;

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: А как вы представляете себе _помощь_? Я рисую нечётные пиксели, а вы чётные?

Comment: Приложите свои рисунки, поясните, почему именно так нарисовали, что именно показалось неправильным.

Comment: @VladD всегда нравился ваш сарказм ))

Comment: @A K https://yadi.sk/i/DrMHHIow3RzoEh вот

Comment: @VladD вот https://yadi.sk/i/DrMHHIow3RzoEh

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/460655/198316 сдается мне это дубль,там даже пример графа есть